# How to display server's TLS certificate details in terminal?

Tags: command-line, openssl, ssl

Having TLS certificate in local file, I can display its details using syntax like:

`openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert_filename`

Is there any way to display remote SMTP/POP3/HTTP server's TLS certificate in this same format in bash terminal?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`openssl s_client -connect server:port` display some informations. Maybe is it sufficient for you. It is not exactly the same format, but it can help.

Comment: You can also add `-starttls PROTO` if the protocol is not native SSL/TLS. For example, `-starttls pop3`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use OpenSSL's `s_client` command to dump the certificate in PEM format (and lots of other stuff, but `-in` doesn't seem to care about it). All you need is some output redirection to convince `x509` to parse that:

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in <(openssl s_client -connect server:443)
```